# React multiple dynamic routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm making a product showcase app which needs to dynamically route between the different levels of categorization and products.

The problem I'm coming up with is this:

[image]

The first half of the picture (the card) is the ProductList component. The second half is the Product component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, NavLink, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import equal from "fast-deep-equal";
import "./ProductList.scss";
import Product from "./Product";

const products = [
  {
    barcode: "8434786605357",
    collection: "2019",
    colorCode: "0",
    colorName: "DENIM",
    familyName: "Denim Pants",
    genericProduct: "PM200338WV7",
    id: 263934,
    image: [
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PM200338WV7/PM200338WV7_000_01_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PM200338WV7/PM200338WV7_000_02_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PM200338WV7/PM200338WV7_000_03_MO.jpg"
    ],
    line: "Men",
    productCode: "PM200338WV7000040",
    productName: "FINSBURY SKINNY FIT LOW WAIST JEANS",
    productNameLang: "en",
    season: "AW",
    size: "40",
    subfamilyName: "Jeans"
  },
  {
    barcode: ["8434786289854", "8434786289847", "8434786289861"],
    collection: "2019",
    colorCode: "0AA",
    colorName: "MULTI",
    familyName: "Dresses",
    genericProduct: "PL952477",
    id: [263935, 263938, 263939],
    image: [
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_01_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_02_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_03_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_01_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_02_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_03_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_01_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_02_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_03_MO.jpg"
    ],
    line: "Women",
    productCode: ["PL9524770AAM", "PL9524770AAL", "PL9524770AAS"],
    productName: "FIONA CROSSOVER DRESS",
    productNameLang: "en",
    season: "SS",
    size: ["M", "L", "S"],
    subfamilyName: "Dresses NS/SS"
  },
  {
    barcode: "8434786258508",
    collection: "2019",
    colorCode: "599",
    colorName: "NACHT",
    familyName: "Swimwear",
    genericProduct: "PMB10211",
    id: 263936,
    image: [
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PMB10211/PMB10211_599_01_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PMB10211/PMB10211_599_02_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PMB10211/PMB10211_599_03_MO.jpg"
    ],
    line: "Men",
    productCode: "PMB10211599XL",
    productName: "ALMONTE SHORT SWIMSUIT",
    productNameLang: "en",
    season: "SS",
    size: "XL",
    subfamilyName: "Swimsuits"
  }
];

const productCategories = [
  {
    grandparent: null,
    level: 1,
    name: "Men",
    parent: null,
    path: "/men"
  },
  {
    grandparent: null,
    level: 2,
    name: "Denim Pants",
    parent: "Men",
    path: "/men/denim-pants"
  },
  {
    grandparent: "Men",
    level: 3,
    name: "Jeans",
    parent: "Denim Pants",
    path: "/men/denim-pants/jeans"
  },
  {
    grandparent: null,
    level: 1,
    name: "Women",
    parent: null,
    path: "/women"
  },
  {
    grandparent: null,
    level: 2,
    name: "Dresses",
    parent: "Women",
    path: "/women/dresses"
  },
  {
    grandparent: "Women",
    level: 3,
    name: "Dresses NS/SS",
    parent: "Dresses",
    path: "/women/dresses/dresses-ns-ss"
  },
  {
    grandparent: null,
    level: 2,
    name: "Swimwear",
    parent: "Men",
    path: "/men/swimwear"
  },
  {
    grandparent: "Men",
    level: 3,
    name: "Swimsuits",
    parent: "Swimwear",
    path: "/men/swimwear/swimsuits"
  },
  {
    grandparent: null,
    level: 2,
    name: "T-Shirts",
    parent: "Men",
    path: "/men/t-shirts"
  },
  {
    grandparent: "Men",
    level: 3,
    name: "SS T-Shirts",
    parent: "T-Shirts",
    path: "/men/t-shirts/ss-t-shirts"
  },
  {
    name: "T-Shirts",
    path: "/women/t-shirts",
    parent: "Women",
    grandparent: null,
    level: 2
  },
  {
    grandparent: "Women",
    level: 3,
    name: "SS T-Shirts",
    parent: "T-Shirts",
    path: "/women/t-shirts/ss-t-shirts"
  }
];

class ProductList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filteredProducts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!equal(this.props, prevProps)) {
      this.filterProducts();
    }
  }

  filterProducts() {
    let productsFiltered = null;
    console.log(products);

    if (this.props.match.params.subfamily !== undefined) {
      productsFiltered = products
        .filter(
          product =>
            product.line
              .toLowerCase()
              .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
              .replace(/\//g, "-") === this.props.match.params.line
        )
        .filter(
          product =>
            product.familyName
              .toLowerCase()
              .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
              .replace(/\//g, "-") === this.props.match.params.family
        )
        .filter(
          product =>
            product.subfamilyName
              .toLowerCase()
              .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
              .replace(/\//g, "-") === this.props.match.params.subfamily
        );
    } else if (this.props.match.params.family !== undefined) {
      productsFiltered = products
        .filter(
          product =>
            product.line
              .toLowerCase()
              .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
              .replace(/\//g, "-") === this.props.match.params.line
        )
        .filter(
          product =>
            product.familyName
              .toLowerCase()
              .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
              .replace(/\//g, "-") === this.props.match.params.family
        );
    } else {
      productsFiltered = products.filter(
        product =>
          product.line
            .toLowerCase()
            .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
            .replace(/\//g, "-") === this.props.match.params.line
      );
    }

    this.setState({
      filteredProducts: productsFiltered
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="product-cards">
          {this.state.filteredProducts.map(product => (
            <Card
              key={product.id}
              className={product.productName + " card"}
              style={{ maxWidth: 145, margin: 10 }}
            >
              <CardActionArea>
                <NavLink to={`/${product.id}`}>
                  <CardMedia
                    component="img"
                    alt="Product Image"
                    height="240"
                    image={product.image[0]}
                    title={product.productName}
                  />
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography
                      gutterBottom
                      variant="h5"
                      component="p"
                      style={{ fontSize: ".8rem" }}
                    >
                      {product.productName}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                </NavLink>
              </CardActionArea>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
        <Route exact path={`/:product`} component={Product} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductList;
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import equal from "fast-deep-equal";
import ImageGallery from "react-image-gallery";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import "./Product.scss";

const productList = [
  {
    barcode: "8434786605357",
    collection: "2019",
    colorCode: "0",
    colorName: "DENIM",
    familyName: "Denim Pants",
    genericProduct: "PM200338WV7",
    id: 263934,
    image: [
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PM200338WV7/PM200338WV7_000_01_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PM200338WV7/PM200338WV7_000_02_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PM200338WV7/PM200338WV7_000_03_MO.jpg"
    ],
    line: "Men",
    productCode: "PM200338WV7000040",
    productName: "FINSBURY SKINNY FIT LOW WAIST JEANS",
    productNameLang: "en",
    season: "AW",
    size: "40",
    subfamilyName: "Jeans"
  },
  {
    barcode: ["8434786289854", "8434786289847", "8434786289861"],
    collection: "2019",
    colorCode: "0AA",
    colorName: "MULTI",
    familyName: "Dresses",
    genericProduct: "PL952477",
    id: [263935, 263938, 263939],
    image: [
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_01_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_02_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_03_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_01_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_02_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_03_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_01_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_02_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PL952477/PL952477_0AA_03_MO.jpg"
    ],
    line: "Women",
    productCode: ["PL9524770AAM", "PL9524770AAL", "PL9524770AAS"],
    productName: "FIONA CROSSOVER DRESS",
    productNameLang: "en",
    season: "SS",
    size: ["M", "L", "S"],
    subfamilyName: "Dresses NS/SS"
  },
  {
    barcode: "8434786258508",
    collection: "2019",
    colorCode: "599",
    colorName: "NACHT",
    familyName: "Swimwear",
    genericProduct: "PMB10211",
    id: 263936,
    image: [
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PMB10211/PMB10211_599_01_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PMB10211/PMB10211_599_02_MO.jpg",
      "http://tools.bexfyinfra.com/bexfy-touch-app-test/PMB10211/PMB10211_599_03_MO.jpg"
    ],
    line: "Men",
    productCode: "PMB10211599XL",
    productName: "ALMONTE SHORT SWIMSUIT",
    productNameLang: "en",
    season: "SS",
    size: "XL",
    subfamilyName: "Swimsuits"
  }
];

class Product extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      product: null,
      images: [
        {
          original: "https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1000/600/",
          thumbnail: "https://picsum.photos/id/1018/250/150/"
        },
        {
          original: "https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1000/600/",
          thumbnail: "https://picsum.photos/id/1015/250/150/"
        },
        {
          original: "https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1000/600/",
          thumbnail: "https://picsum.photos/id/1019/250/150/"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!equal(this.props, prevProps)) {
      this.filterProduct();
    }
  }

  filterProduct() {
    let productId = this.props.match.params.product;
    console.log(productId);
    let selectedProduct = productList.filter(
      product => product.id == productId
    );
    console.log(selectedProduct);
    let images = selectedProduct[0].image.map(img => {
      return { original: img, thumbnail: img };
    });
    console.log(productId);
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState({
      product: selectedProduct,
      images: images
    });
  }

  handleChangeSize = event => {
    this.setState({ selectedSize: event.target.value });
  };

  handleChangeColor = event => {
    this.setState({ selectedColor: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.product !== null && (
          <>
            <ImageGallery items={this.state.images} thumbnailPosition="left" />
            <div className="product-description">
              <h3>{this.state.product[0].productName}</h3>
              <h5>
                {Array.isArray(this.state.product[0].productCode)
                  ? this.state.product[0].productCode[0]
                  : this.state.product[0].productCode}
              </h5>
              {Array.isArray(this.state.product[0].size) ? (
                <form
                  styles={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexWrap: "wrap"
                  }}
                >
                  <FormControl styles={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
                    <span className="product-label">Size:</span>
                    <Select
                      value={this.state.selectedSize}
                      onChange={this.handleChangeSize}
                    >
                      {this.state.product[0].size.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                          <MenuItem
                            key={index}
                            value={this.state.product[0].size[index]}
                          >
                            {this.state.product[0].size[index]}
                          </MenuItem>
                        );
                      })}
                    </Select>
                  </FormControl>
                </form>
              ) : (
                <div>
                  <span className="product-label">Size:</span>
                  {this.state.product[0].size}
                </div>
              )}
              {Array.isArray(this.state.product[0].colorCode) ? (
                <form
                  styles={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexWrap: "wrap"
                  }}
                >
                  <FormControl styles={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
                    <span className="product-label">Color:</span>
                    <Select
                      value={this.state.selectedColor}
                      onChange={this.handleChangeColor}
                    >
                      {this.state.product[0].colorCode.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                          <MenuItem
                            key={index}
                            value={this.state.product[0].colorCode[index]}
                          >
                            {this.state.product[0].colorName[index]}
                          </MenuItem>
                        );
                      })}
                    </Select>
                  </FormControl>
                </form>
              ) : (
                <div>
                  <span className="product-label">Color:</span>
                  {this.state.product[0].colorName}
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Product;
```

I have read the Router documentation but I don't usually use complex dynamic parameters. I would have solved a similar problem with the "exact" prop to the route but it didn't work as its dynamically generated.

I would want for the ProductList component to not show up when I'm in the Product View, and viceversa. Is there a way to do that?

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

CodeSandbox playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-firefly-tm9r0?fontsize=14

Comment: You should copy/paste the pertinent parts of your code directly in your question. What have you tried with your router? Did you read the react-router documentation? What parts do you need help with?

Comment: edited the post :)

Comment: "I don't usually use complex dynamic parameters" I would design the `Product` component in such a way that the only parameter needed in the URL is the product's id.

Comment: It would be good that you can handle the items by the parameters of the url, so if you go to the /{Id} it would redirect you to the product that you want to see. Regarding the Issue that you have both components in the same Screen you can show the Product in a Modal or something similar to improve the UX.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read the Router documentation but I don't usually use complex dynamic parameters.

I suggest giving only the product `id` as a parameter to the route. More complex routes are usually not necessary. All of the rest of the product data, including image URLs, should be stored in state.

> I would want for the ProductList component to not show up when I'm in the Product View, and viceversa. Is there a way to do that?

Yes, you should separate your product list from your router. There should be two separate classes. One that renders the product list. And one that registers the routes and chooses between the product list and the product details. Specifically, you should use the `<Switch/>` component from `react-router`.